# Lazy loading technique for UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c

I have an IOS application, which uses a UICollectionView for displaying a horizontal grid of cells. All i need, is a clever way of (lazy) loading data when the user reaches the end of my UICollectionView. The code i use now is :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    GridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:Cell forIndexPath:indexPath];


    /**
     TODO
     - Find a good way to check if the user has reach the end of the grid
     - This next piece of code is for demonstration purposes. A real check has to be
     done yet!!!
     **/

    // releases is my datasource //

    if(indexPath.row == (releases.count - 1)) {
        [self getNextListData];
    }

    return cell; // <-- finally return the cell


}
```

The problem with this code is : if a user scrolls really fast to the end, he has to scroll back and forth to load more items. This is really not user friendly and i need a better way to load items when needed.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't know the count in the list to begin with, is this the case?

Answer (score 4):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` has a delegate, `UIScrollViewDelegate` that has a bunch of methods related to scrolling. In one of these delegate methods (such as `scrollViewDidBeginDecelerating:`), you can check to see how far along the page you are, with the `contentOffset` and `contentSize` properties. If you're close to the end (defined by whatever % is the end for you), fetch more data.

An advantage to using a scrollview method is that it will not cause `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to be slower (by forcing it to run code for every collectionview unnecessarily).

This is basically the same technique that Apple suggests for lazy-loading of UITableView data's, applied slightly differently. They have some sample code for that as well (such as [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html))

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this problem with table views, I had to do some user testing. I found that if I started my load 10 cells before the end of the table, the new cell should be ready. Assuming that you are doing background loading of the data, that is.

```
if (indexPath.row >= [releases count] - 10)
    [self getNextListData];
```

You would want to do some testing to see what number works for you.

In addition, I also had a loading indicator cell. In my number of rows in section callback, I always returned 1 extra.

```
return [releases count] + 1;
```

At the start of my cell for row callback I returned a special loading indicator cell.

```
if (indexPath.row == [releases count])
    return [JLTActivityCell sharedInstance];
```

I'm not sure exactly how that advice will apply to collection views, but hopefully it gets you pointed in a good direction.